# Protocol requires that delegate inherit from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol `ShareDelegate` that looks like this:

```
protocol ShareDelegate : class {
    func share(event: EventJSONModel, skipToTime time: CMTime?, view: UIView, completion: @escaping () -> ())
}

extension ShareDelegate where Self: UIViewController {
    func share(event: EventJSONModel, skipToTime time: CMTime? = nil, view: UIView, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {

    }
}
```

Then when I use this as a delegate:

```
weak var delegate: ShareDelegate?
```

and then call the delegate function:

```
delegate?.share(event: event, view: view, completion: completion)
```

it gives me the following error

`'ShareDelegate' requires that 'ShareDelegate' inherit from 'UIViewController'`

If I remove the `skipToTime time: CMTime?` part of the extension it works fine. Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the interface is different between the protocol and the default implementation.

protocol:

```
func share(event: EventJSONModel, skipToTime time: CMTime?, view: UIView, completion: @escaping () -> ())
```

Extension:

```
func share(event: EventJSONModel, skipToTime time: CMTime? = nil, view: UIView, completion: @escaping () -> ())
```

So you've declared `skipToTime` to be optional in the extension with a default value, so when calling it and skipping that value, you are specifically calling the version that is confined to `UIViewController`

UPDATE:

You should be able to restrict usage of your ShareDelegate protocol so that it only works with UIViewControllers like this:

```
protocol ShareDelegate: class where Self: UIViewController {
    func share()
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. How would I get rid of the error if I wanted to keep it this way (calling the version confined to a `UIViewController`)? All my ShareDelegates are always UIViewControllers anyway

Comment: You could keep the interface the same (I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error as they are slightly different), there are a few options available... restrict the protocol to either only work on a UIViewController, or there is another option I'm testing now as I'm not 100% sure it would work

Comment: I've added some code at the end of my answer which will mean that any delegate is also a UIViewController

Answer (score 1):

```
extension ShareDelegate where Self: UIViewController {
    func share(...) {

    }
}
```

Because of this code above, you need a `UIViewController` to confirm to the delegate using extension it would look something like that

```
extension UIViewController: ShareDelegate {
    func share(...) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have extended a UIViewController and that's not the problem. I just found it's something to do with my function parameters, I've updated my question.